# Nginx, highload, googlebot

Tags: nginx, highload

У нас есть сервер на котором работают ~850 сайтов, всё отлично!
НО, когда приходит googlebot, появляются колоссальные пики. Если бы сайтов было поменьше нагрузка тоже была бы меньше и на это можно было бы не обращать внимания, но их столько.

Как, если это возможно, снизить нагрузку не уменьшая количества сайтов и не запрещая бота (ведь он полезный)?

Заранее благодарим за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

[Кеширование](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache), правильные robots.txt, и [ограничение количества соединений](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) по ip.

**Обновление**

Кеширование динамически формирующихся страниц позволит снизить число обращений к бекенду, а значит освободит системные ресурсы. В `robots.txt` увеличить период времени через который краулеры заходят на сайт. С помощью `limit_conn_module` можно ограничить число одновременных соединений с гугловских ip-адресов и тем уменьшить нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: "можно ограничить число одновременных соединений с гугловских ip-адресов" - а гугл в таком случае не будет считать, что сайт лежит и ухудшать рейтинг?

Comment: как раз для этого robots.txt и существует. Гугл понимает, что ему задосить Вас раз плюнуть. Ничего плохого не случиться. Главное, что бы он успевал проиндескировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy точно не знаю. возвращается 503 статус, думаю гугл трактует это правильно и не понизит.

Answer (score 0):

Немного дополню подробный ответ сверху.

При ограничении количества соединений указывайте код ответа на 503, а 429

```
limit_conn_status 429;
```

Это легитимный код, который с пониманием принимается поисковыми ботами.

Comment: Для дополнения к ответам, предпочтительнее использовать комментарии к нему.